# Bokeh row layout gets Crowded with sizing or width option

Tags: python, bokeh

I am just looking to create a column with two rows each having multiple inputs.

```
r1 = row(children=[transaction_type, 
instrument,master_list_type,order_type,product_type, 
duration,square_off,trailing_ticks],sizing_mode='scale_width')

r2 = row(children=[quantity,price,trigger_price,disclosed_quantity,stop_loss],sizing_mode='scale_width')

lo = column(r1,r2)
#show(row(transaction_type, 
instrument,master_list_type,order_type,product_type, 
duration,square_off,trailing_ticks))

curdoc().add_root(lo)
```

idea is to get a relevant inputs in rows. I get output like

[image]

If I don't give `sizing_mode`, they are not crowded but each take too much space.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is always declare the width and height of each element. When you are putting them in a row (or column), give width (or height) equal to sum of width (or height) of individual components + padding required.

Comment: Thanks, for answering, can you please give me an example.